# JavaScript não pega em páginas adicionadas posteriormente

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

Estou com um problema, o que me gera uma dúvida grande.

Estou desenvolvendo um site que possui uma estrutura padrão, que faz chamadas GET no `Jquery` para buscar novas páginas HTML para determinadas partes da página.

Exemplo: clico em um link e a mudança de páginas é feita sem que a página se recarregue.

Porém, aí está o problema. As páginas adicionadas posteriormente por Ajax, que tem alguns elementos que utilizam código em `JavaScript`, como slides, gráficos, mapas, entre outros elementos, são adicionadas corretamente, mas esses elementos citados não funcionam, apenas se forem incorporados logo no início do site (assim que o site é carregado).

O que devo fazer para que isso não ocorra e que esses elementos funcionem corretamente?

Comment: Bem vindo ao Sopt, bom primeiro, cade o seu codigo? não podemos adivinhar seu problema. cuidado com a informalidade ao postar, nenhum codigo PEGA, ele pode copilar, funcionar, gerar erros no console etc.

Comment: Valeu Isvaldo!
Na verdade,  o problema é muito mais teórico. Na verdade não tem nem como eu colocar algum trecho aqui pra vocês, pois isso é no site inteiro, com códigos bem grandes. Gostaria de saber se, na teoria, isso deveria acontecer, pelo fato de puxar uma página posteriormente e tudo mais.

Comment: @RenéGustavo o seu problema está no seu JQuery, que somente pega os itens existentes na tela, e quando você faz a requisição Ajax, ele não se preocupa em colocar os eventos e funções no seu novo código. Por exemplo `$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});`isto é um evendo click padrão, mas se você usar o seu Ajax não irá funcionar. Você teria que usar:     `$('#salvaHorarioAvulso').on('click', function () {
        CriaHorarioAvulso();
    });` desta forma o JQuery sempre fica escutando e vendo os códigos da página.

Comment: @MarlonTiedt, entendi e sei como é isso. Isto tem relação com a questão de funções que carregam mapas, gráficos entre outras coisas, no momento do carregamento, sem nenhuma ação do usuário?

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que esteja utilizando a tecnologia errada para o fim esperado. É sim possível fazer o que quer utilizando javascript + jquery, porém não é a melhor forma de se fazer.

Para fazer da forma que está fazendo eu recomendo criar novos arquivos com apenas o trecho do código que será alterado, exemplo:

index.html

```
...
<div id="container">
 [aqui_vai_o_conteúdo_carregado]
</div>
...
```

external.html

```
<div>
  <h2>Um titulo qualquer</h2>
  <p> Esse é o conteúdo que será carregado dentro do container ao clicar em algum link </p>
</div>
```

Na teoria você deve carregar apenas o conteúdo necessário dentro do container ao invés de recarregar todo o html, o que seria mais custoso para processar. E só depois desse carregamento é que você deve inicializar os plugins. Fazer a verificação desse carregamento com javascript e jquery pode ser bem chato, por isso recomendo frameworks próprios para isso.

Recomendo estudar: AngularJS, EmberJS
Ou se prefere algo mais leve e simples: ReactJS, MithrilJS, RiotJS

Todos esses frameworks possuem métodos exclusivos para desenvolvimento de SPA (Single Page Applications), como binder de conteúdo, rotas, inicializadores etc...

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo comentário amigo! O que está falando pra eu fazer, em relação aos arquivos com trechos de código, é exatamente o que eu faço, mas infelizmente acontece o que eu te disse. Vou estudar o que me recomendou. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o $.getScript para carregar o js externo. Veja esse exemplo que testei aqui localmente.

O que é feito o seguinte: É usado o $.get para puxar o arquivo teste.html, e o $.getScript para puxar o js correspondente a ele.

No teste.html tem um botão com onclick, e a função desse botão está no js.js.

**base.html**

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {

$("#chamada1").click(function() {

$.get("teste.html", function( data ) {
$.getScript("js.js");
$("#conteudo").html(data);
}); 

}); 

});
</script>

<input type="button" value="chamada1" id="chamada1" />

<div id="conteudo"></div>
```

**teste.html**

```
<input type="button" value="clique" onclick="alerta1()">
```

**js.js**

```
function alerta1() {
alert("esse é o alerta 1");
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta amigo!

Eu entendi perfeitamente o que disse, porém tenho uma dúvida. O mesmo código .js que estou usando nessa página "teste.html" que está sendo inserido pelo GET, estou usando na página estrutural, para onde é importada a teste. Mesmo assim eu devo usar o .getScript?

Comment: Se você já faz a chamada do js na página principal não precisa puxar pelo getScript também.

Comment: Entendi! Infelizmente não funciona os JS nessas páginas externas adicionadas posteriormente.